# Django url No Activity matches the given query?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, slug

I'm trying to write a slug field so users can view my `activity_detail` page.  I think I wrote the code right, but I'm getting 404 error with `No Activity matches the given query.`
. Here is my code:

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . views import activity_list, activity_detail, activity_index

app_name = 'activity'

urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^$', activity_index, name='index'),
re_path(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', activity_list, name='list'),
re_path(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', activity_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

my views.py:

```
def activity_detail(request, year, slug=None):
    activity = get_object_or_404(Activity, year=year, slug=slug)
    context = {
    'activity': activity,
    }
    return render(request, "activity/detail.html", context)
```

I'm planning to call my url addresses from the browser as follows:

```
http://localhost/activity/
http://localhost/activity/2018/
http://localhost/activity/2018/myactivity
```

Comment: Well there is no activity with the slug `myactivity` and in the year `2018`.

Comment: The code looks fine, but that does not mean the URL itself is *sensical*, you need to query for an URL that has an `Activity` in the database that matches.

Comment: The error however suggests that you query for a `Post`, not an `Activity`, are you sure you share the relevant parts here?

Comment: sory I put it wrong. rewrite the error message

Comment: What URL are you querying?

Comment: `http://localhost/activity/2018/myactivity`

Comment: it could be that your database doesn't have the entry for year=2018, slug='myactivity', did you ensure it before? manage.py shell comes handy on this.

Comment: I am sure. The slug field is generated automatically when I add it to the database.

Comment: @mthnglac: what if you make a query `SELECT * FROM app_activity WHERE year=2018 AND slug='myactivity'`? Can you share the result of `SELECT * FROM app_activity`.

Comment: I printed the data when I did query without year, looks like there is no problem. But  after I tried with filter without year on views.py but nothing has changed.

Comment: I wrote `print(slug)` before `activity = get_object_or_404 (Activity, slug = slug)` in views.py file and I checked the value, its true . but then I can't get results when I write `print (activity)`. So here's a mistake and it doesn't return the activity object to me. When I removed `slug = slug` , it brings the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with this approach is that if you do not specify the `slug`, then the view is called with `slug=None`, and thus then you filter with `slug=None`, which will fail.

You can solve this with a `None` check:

```
def activity_detail(request, year, slug=None):
    filter = {'year': year}
    if slug is not None:
        filter['slug'] = slug
    activity = get_object_or_404(Activity, **filter)
    context = {
        'activity': activity,
    }
    return render(request, "activity/detail.html", context)
```

So here we first make an initial `filter` dictionary that contains only the `year`, and if `slug` is not `None`, then we add an extra filter.

I find however the `year` filter rather strange: typically there will be *multiple* `Activity`s for a given `year`, so then this will error.

In case you obtain an error like:

> No Activity matches the given query.

This thus means that there is *no* record in your databases that has the given year, and slug. The 404 error is not a problem: it simply says that for that given URL, there is no corresponding `Activity` object available. So it makes sense to return such error.

In case you want to display *all* the `Activity`s that match the filter, you can use the [**`get_list_or_404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404).